# multiple check box selection and print the checked row title alone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have one table view with showing button, title. now i need to  check / uncheck the cell with image on cell.And at last what are the checked image cell title i need to print.How to do that?

my code:

```
var selectedIndexPathArray = Array<NSIndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BlockedTableViewCell

        let pending = allnames?[indexPath.row]

        cell.NameLabel.text = pending?.name


        return cell
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

My cell check box image name : `'checked.png'   'unchecked.png'`

Comment: Do you want to print the title of the cell when you select the cell?

Comment: yes, also need to chnage the button mage to checked ,.and it have multiple check box selection too...and need to print the checked cell title alone.....( note : if i first checked and again uncheck then this title and all should not print )

Comment: You can create a custom class for your UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Image :**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BlockedTableViewCell

            let pending = allnames?[indexPath.row]

            cell.NameLabel.text = pending?.name
           if selectedIndexPathArray.contains(indexPath) {
             cell.checkboxBtn.setImage( UIImage(named:"checked.png"), for: .normal)          
           } else {
             cell.checkboxBtn.setImage( UIImage(named:"unchecked.png"), for: .normal)           
           }


            return cell
        }
```

**Printing Title :**

```
func printSelectedItems(){

   for indexPath in selectedIndexPathArray {
      let item = allnames?[indexPath.row]
      print(item.name)
   }
}
```